# Spring MVC instantiate object on request attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Assume I am creating a `PrinterService` class that has a `AbstractPrinter` object. `AbstractPrinter` is subclassed by classes such as `HPPrinter`, `FilePrinter` etc.

The exact kind of printer object to be used is mentioned in the `RequestParam` object passed to my `Controller` (it is a request attribute).

Is there any way I can inject the right kind of concrete printer class using Spring? 
All the other dependencies are injected using `@Autowired` annotation. How to inject this one?

Comment: Your dependency is supposed to be injected only once. What happens if you get many request with different request param values ? You get a different printer each time ?

Comment: Yes, the Printer instantiated will be dependent on the request object .. once a Printer object is created, we can reuse that for other request with the same parameters

Comment: But you agree that if a different request is received with different parameter, you'll need anotther printer. Where can you store it if you allready have one ? Or you replace previous one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and load a factory of `AbstractPrinter` objects during container startup as shown below and dynamically call the respective the `AbstractPrinter`'s `print()` (or your own method) based on the input parameter (comes from controller) to the service.

In the below code for `PrinterServiceImpl` class, the main point is that all of the `List<AbstractPrinter>` will be injected by Spring container (depends upon how many implementation classes you provide like HPPrinter, etc..). Then you will load those beans into a `Map` during container startup with printerType as key.

```
@Controller
public class YourController {

   @Autowired
   private PrinterService printerService;

   public X myMethod(@RequestParam("input") String input) {
     printerService.myServiceMethod(input);
     //return X
   } 
}
```

**PrinterServiceImpl class:**

```
public class PrinterServiceImpl implements  PrinterService {

    @Autowired
    private List<AbstractPrinter> abstractPrinters;

    private static final Map<String,AbstractPrinter> myPrinters = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadPrinters() {
        for(AbstractPrinter printer : abstractPrinters) {
            myPrinters.put(printer.getPrinterType(), printer);
        }
    }

    //Add your other Autowired dependencies here

    @Override
    public void myServiceMethod(String input){//get input from controller
        AbstractPrinter abstractPrinter= myPrinters.get(input);
        abstractPrinter.print();//dynamically calls print() depending on input
    }
}
```

**HPPrinter class:**

```
@Component
public class HPPrinter implements AbstractPrinter {
    @Override
    public String getPrinterType() {
        return "HP";
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
      // Your print code
    }
}
```

**FilePrinter class:**

```
@Component
public class FilePrinter implements AbstractPrinter {
    @Override
    public String getPrinterType() {
        return "FILE";
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
      // Your print code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dedicated `PrinterService` instance per `AbstractPrinter` concrete class. For example you could achieve this using [Spring configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts) which follow the factory pattern:

```
@Configuration
public class PrinterServiceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private HPPrinter hpPrinter;

    @Autowired
    private FilePrinter filePrinter;

    @Bean 
    public PrinterService hpPrinterService() {
       return new PrinterService(hpPrinter);
    }

    @Bean 
    public PrinterService filePrinterService() {
       return new PrinterService(filePrinter);
    }

    public PrinterService findPrinterService(PrinterType type){
       if (type == HP) 
          return hpPrinterService(); 
       ....  
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, inject `PrinterServiceConfiguration` then call `findPrinterService` with the right printer type.

Don't forget to add `PrinterServiceConfiguration` at your configuration `@Import`.

If the list of printer is dynamic you could switch to prototype bean :

```
@Configuration
public class PrinterServiceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private List<AbstractPrinter> printers;

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)    
    public PrinterService createPrinterService(PrinterType type){
      return new PrinterService(findPrinterByType(type)); 
    }

    private Printer findPrinterByType(PrinterType type) {
      // iterate over printers then return the printer that match type
      // throw exception if no printer found
    }
}
```